# Do you know a clever way to minimize USB latency (USB sound)?

Tags: usb, virtualization

So in linux I run a virtual machine -> Because I need my MIDI compatible + asio.

But I was thinking, if anyone out there knew some tricks/hacks to improve latency with USB.
(if it's even possible)

Answer (score 1):

Use a real time or low latency kernel, you can install the later one in ubuntu with the following command:

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-lowlatency`

Then make sure to select the lowlatency kernel in the grub menu when turning on your computer.

I would also say avoid virtual machines if you can as they'll definetly introduce latency,

Sam

Comment: Cant use ASIO in linux, thats why i need the VM